# How to remove default links on navigation bar and change their order

Tags: activeadmin

As title,

I want to remove the default links **assets**, **comments**

and change the remaining links order, how to do it ? thanks

[image]

Comment: did you find solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In initializers/active_admin.rb

```
config.comments_menu = false
```

That will remove comments from the menu.

If you want to customize the menu further, remove assets, or keep comments and move them to a dropdown you can build a menu.  Just omit any label that you'd like hidden from the menu.

```
config.comments_menu = false
#....
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.build_menu do |menu|
    menu.add label: 'Dashboard', priority: 0
    menu.add label: 'Revenue', priority: 3
    menu.add label: 'Costs', priority: 4
    menu.add label: 'Categories', priority: 5
    menu.add label: 'Users & Comments', priority: 6
    menu.add label: 'Comments', parent: 'Users & Comments', url: "/admin/comments"
  end
end
```

Comment: This has been changed in activeadmin 1.0 to ```config.comments_menu = false```

Comment: Thanks for that quainjn.  I've been looking all over for that.  It shows in the changelog that they made that change, but from all I could tell it takes a block.